# Is the input word in alphabetical order?

Tags: javascript, alphabetic

I'm writing a function that will return `true` or `false` in regards to whether or not the input string is in alphabetical order. I'm getting `undefined` and not sure what I'm missing

```js
function is_alphabetic(str) {
  let result = true;
  for (let count = 1, other_count = 2; count >= str.length - 1, other_count >= str.length; count++,
    other_count++) {
    if (str.at[count] > str.at[other_count]) {
      let result = false
    }
    return result
  }
}
console.log(is_alphabetic('abc'));
```

Comment: you are returning inside the loop, return statement should be outside the loop body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have put `return` statement inside the for loop, it should be outside the loop body.

Your code is also not correct. `count` should start from 0, `other_count` should start from 1.

`count >= str.length - 1` should be `count < str.length - 1` (this condition is completely unnecessary in your code because `other_count < str.length` should be the terminating condition in the loop)

and

`other_count >= str.length` should be `other_count < str.length`

Here's your corrected code

```js
function is_alphabetic(str) {
  let result = true;

  for (let count = 0, other_count = 1; other_count < str.length; count++, other_count++) {
      if (str[count] > str[other_count]) {
         result = false
      }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(is_alphabetic('abc'));
```

Here's an alternative approach

```js
function is_alphabetic(str){
   return str.split('')
             .every((c, idx) => str[idx + 1] ? c < str[idx + 1] : true);
}

console.log(is_alphabetic('abc'));
```

Keep in mind that if you want the comparisons between the characters to be case-insensitive, then convert the string in to lowercase before comparing the characters.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. I used `.localeCompare()` as this will ignore small/capital differences and will also deal reasonably with language specific characters, like German Umlauts.

```js
function is_alphabetic(str){
  return !str.split('').some((v,i,a)=>i&&v.localeCompare(a[i-1])<0)
}
['abcdefg','aacccRt','ashhe','xyz','aüv'].forEach(s=> console.log(s,is_alphabetic(s)) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is easier if you compare the string using this function:

```
var sortAlphabets = function(text) {
    return text.split('').sort().join('');
};
```

This produces results like:

```
sortAlphabets("abghi")
output: "abghi"
```

Or:

```
sortAlphabets("ibvjpqjk")
output: "bijjkpqv"
```

if you want to know if your string is alphabetically sorted, you might use:

```
var myString = "abcezxy"
sortAlphabets(myString) == myString
output: false
```

Or in case, you want to create an specific function:

```
function isSorted(myString) {
    return sortAlphabets(myString) == myString
}
```

And for that case, you can use:

```
isSorted("abc")
```

```js
var sortAlphabets = function(text) {
        return text.split('').sort().join('');
    };

function isSorted(myString) {
        return sortAlphabets(myString) == myString
    }
    
 alert("is abc sorted: " + isSorted("abc"));
  alert("is axb sorted: " + isSorted("axb"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

1. Your return statement is in your for-loop. To avoid such mistakes you can get a code-formatter like prettier;
2. Your for-loop condition is invalid. Keep in mind that the second part of the for-loop statement is supposed to be `true` to do an iteration and `false` to stop doing iterations. In this case, your condition `count >= str.length-1, other_count >= str.length` will first evaluate `count >= str.length-1`, discard the result because of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator#:~:text=The%20comma%20operator%20(%20%2C%20)%20evaluates,rightmost%20of%20its%20member%20expressions.), evaluate `other_count >= str.length` which immediately resolves to `false`.

These two things together make it so your function never returns, which the javascript runtime interprets as `undefined`.

Hope this helps you understand what went wrong. But like many other pointed out, there are better ways to tackle the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to compare the string with its corresponding 'sorted' one

```js
let string = 'abc'.split('').join('');
let sortedString = 'abc'.split('').sort().join('');

console.log(sortedString === sortedString)

let string2 = 'dbc'.split('').join('');
let sortedString2 = 'dbc'.split('').sort().join('');

console.log(string2 === sortedString2)
```